# How to ensure controllers/views reference the correct instance of the model class: MVC Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, model-view-controller, design-patterns, singleton

As per the title, I'm wondering how to safely swap the instance of my Model class using MVC.

I have created a singleton Model Class, but I have added a delete method to "safely" swap models when creating a new model, or loading a model from another file.

Here is how I currently have it working, but it doesn't feel right. I feel like I should be passing a model instance into both the controller and the view, and updating said instance every time a new model is created.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired effect?

```
# Singleton Model class
class Model():
    active_model = None
    _can_create_instance = True
    
    @staticmethod
    def delete_current_model():
        Model.active_model = None
        Model._can_create_instance = True
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.active_model is None:
            cls.active_model = super(Model, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.active_model
    
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        if Model._can_create_instance:
            Model._can_create_instance = False
            self.name = name
        
class Controller():
    def __init__(self, view) -> None:
        self.view = view
        
    @property
    def model(self):
        return Model.active_model
        
    def handle_create_new_model(self, name):
        self.model.delete_current_model()
        _ = Model(name)
        
class View():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.controller = None  # type: Controller

    @property
    def model(self):
        return Model.active_model

    def set_controller(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        
    def create_new_model(self, name):
        self.controller.handle_create_new_model(name)
        
        
def main():
    
    _ = Model("model 1")
    
    view_1 = View()
    view_controller1 = Controller(view_1)
    view_1.set_controller(view_controller1)
    
    print(f'View 1 {view_1.model.name}: {id(view_1.model)}')
    print(f'Controller 1 {view_controller1.model.name}: {id(view_controller1.model)}')
    
    # Simulate event to create new model in view 1
    view_1.create_new_model("model 2")
    
    print(f'View 1 {view_1.model.name}: {id(view_1.model)}')
    print(f'Controller 1 {view_controller1.model.name}: {id(view_controller1.model)}')
    
    # example of protection caused by use of singleton
    _ = Model("model 3")
    
    print(f'View 1 {view_1.model.name}: {id(view_1.model)}')
    print(f'Controller 1 {view_controller1.model.name}: {id(view_controller1.model)}')
    
    # Result:
    # View 1 model 1: 3073102003360
    # Controller 1 model 1: 3073102003360
    # View 1 model 2: 3073102003072
    # Controller 1 model 2: 3073102003072
    # View 1 model 2: 3073102003072
    # Controller 1 model 2: 3073102003072

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Imho: You should use a dependency injection container (DIC), in order to inject the same _model_ (as you name it) instance into both the _controller_ and the _view_ through [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). And you should avoid the use of [singletons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI).#

Comment: I agree with everything you said however, dependency injection will cause a problem if "main" creates a new instance of the "model" unless the dependency for each view is re-injected into each view/controller by "main" every time the "model" changes. (think loading a new file that replaces the model)

I actually started off by doing this, but my current project has 8 views and 8 controllers, so it got difficult to maintain.

I have also been looking into observer patterns, but this is also trivial as the entire model is being swapped out.